# Angular - How to set corporate proxy for http request

Tags: angular, proxy

Suppose my corporate proxy - >>http://proxy.comapny.com:8080
and Http url - >> http://15.232.2.216/api/get/data?elm=STATE (local network ip adderss)
angular running on my ip - >> http://15.232.1.178:4200

http url ip address is changed depending on url input so not a solution to set proxy as ip address in proxy.config.json and run command ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.js
like

```
 "*/api" : {
        "target" : "http://15.232.2.216",
        "secure" : false,
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
```

What is solution on above problem.

Answer (score 0):

First with the help of your corporate network team assign static ip to your system. So IP won't change and you can use that url for setting up a proxy.

Comment: User specific ip address of device which needed at login form we fetch that ip address and create to webserver install on that device so suppose user provide ip as 10.235.0.1 the http request is http://10.235.0.1/api/get/data?elm=STATE so no need of static ip.